# java.lang.NullPointerException with arrays

Tags: java

Hey the names in the program are in portuguese but I think its understandable, if you have any doubt just ask and i'll translate.

So I'm getting a `NullPointerException` with these. The array Vector_Canais is initialized in the constructor:

```
public Box(int capacidade) {
        Time a = new Time();
        Vector_Canais = new Canal[DEFAULT_SIZE];
    }

public static void novoCanal() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        Cnl = in.nextLine();
        Vector_Canais[i] = new Canal(Cnl);      
        i++;
    }

    public static String listaCanais(int i) {
        return (Vector_Canais[i].getCanal());
    }

public static void listaCanais() {
        for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
            if (Box.listaCanais(a) != null) {
                System.out.println(Box.listaCanais(a));
            }
        }
```

i is initialized at 0.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please copy/paste the stack trace from your exception, and show us the line in your code that caused it. Also show the code that initializes `Vector_Canais`.

Comment: Is `Vector_Canais` a class or a variable name?

Comment: Better post *all* your code. What you have posted doesn't make any sense. For example, `Time a = new Time();` does nothing - the scope of `a` is the method and you don't use it, so why define it?

Comment: on which line exception is coming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you haven't initialized the array `Vector_Canais` or you haven't initialized all of its members (for instance, `novoCanal` hasn't been called 100 times before). Remember, making an array of size 100 (of a class) means making an array of 100 `null` slots, not 100 objects. Until you call a constructor for each of them, they may throw this.

Comment: I think thats my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help. If this really is the solution for your problem, please consider marking the answer as correct.

Comment: Followup question: how do I make the rest 99 channels if I don't want to/can't  make them all at the same time?

Comment: In that case, you can modify your null check to look like this: `if (Vector_Canais[a] != null && Box.listaCanais(a) != null)`
This way, you don't *have* to initialize them all before looping, but the loop ignores those that haven't been initialized.

Comment: Thanks i've made a counter though and compared the cycle with the counter so it would only scan the channels created.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown where `Vector_Canais` is initialized - my guess is you are *not* initializing it.

Try this:

```
static private Vector_Canais Canal[] = new Canal[100]; // for example
```

Comment: Java conventions! Variable names start with lowercase ;)

Comment: @m0skit0 Come on... this guy is waaay off coping with naming conventions. I'm just trying to get him up and running with as little info as possible in case it fries his brain

Comment: Sorry I am here:

`public Box(int capacidade) {
  Time a = new Time();
  Vector_Canais = new Canal[DEFAULT_SIZE];
 }`

Comment: "edit" your question and add what code you need to there, not here in a comment